# Сортировка в ArrayList

Tags: java, android, массивы

У меня есть ArrayList со сногими данными. Нужно отсортировать по TicketPrice и в другом Фрагменте показать. Но я в первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. Раньше массивы обычным способом сортировал. То есть с For().

**Вот сам ArrayList:**

```
ArrayList<TicketObjects> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new TicketObjects("FRU","13:45","16.09.2015","FRU","13:45","16.09.2015","1ч 15мин","15000",R.drawable.logo_flyduba));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("OSS","15:43","16.09.2015","SFD","17:45","16.09.2015","1ч 55мин","16000", R.drawable.logo_kazak));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("CVC","11:54","16.09.2015","TRW","12:44","16.09.2015","2ч 15мин","13000", R.drawable.logo_pegasus_logo));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("KTH", "23:55", "16.09.2015", "GHG", "18:33", "16.09.2015", "1ч 30мин", "10000", R.drawable.logo_turkish_airlines));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("FRU","13:45","16.09.2015","FRU","13:45","16.09.2015","1ч 15мин","15000",R.drawable.logo_flyduba));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("OSS","15:43","16.09.2015","SFD","17:45","16.09.2015","1ч 55мин","16000", R.drawable.logo_kazak));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("CVC","11:54","16.09.2015","TRW","12:44","16.09.2015","2ч 15мин","13000", R.drawable.logo_pegasus_logo));
    items.add(new TicketObjects("KTH", "23:55", "16.09.2015", "GHG", "18:33", "16.09.2015", "1ч 30мин", "10000", R.drawable.logo_turkish_airlines));


    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(items);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**TickeObjects:**

```
public TicketObjects(String departCode, String departTime, String departDate,
                     String arriveCode, String arriveTime, String arriveDate,
                     String flyTime, String ticketPrice, int airlineLogo) {


    this.departCode = departCode;
    this.departTime = departTime;
    this.departDate = departDate;
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
    this.flyTime = flyTime;
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
}
```

вот сама сортировка, но почему-то он весь красный, да и что передавать после сортировки без понятия...

```
ch_recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.ch_recyclerview);

    Collections.sort(Tickets_all_fragment.items, new Comparator<TicketObjects>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TicketObjects lhs, TicketObjects rhs) {
            return rhs.getTicketPrice().compareTo(rhs.getTicketPrice());
        }
    });

    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(Tickets_all_fragment.items);
    ch_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
```

**Подскажите, что я неправильно делаю?**

Comment: Ход решения верный, сделали кастомный `compare`. Как минимум есть опечатка: вместо `return rhs.getTicketPrice().compareTo(rhs.getTicketPrice()` должно быть `return lhs.getTicketPrice().compareTo(rhs.getTicketPrice()`

Comment: Плюс добавлю, что если Вы в сортировку передаете ваш список вот таким образом "FirstFragment.items", то получается что вы вызываете её вне фрагмента, что непонятно зачем. И ругается у вас из-за того, что просит ваш items сделать статическим. Просто вызовите сортировку, до того как запихаете список в адаптер

Comment: Зачем? Просто чтобы все эти данные заново не переписать...

Comment: Так неправильно?

Comment: Nick Volynkin, что нужно передать во втором Фрагменте на adapter?

Comment: так а что мешает список сортировать после того как он сгенерировался?

Comment: Почему то и на первом фрагменте сортируется!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так обратиться (`FirstFragment.items`) можно только к статической переменной `items` класса `FirstFragment`.

После сортировки первый аргумент метода `sort()` станет отсортированным.

Я надеюсь, в классе `TicketObject` у вас есть `метод getTicketPrice()` (и он `public`)?

Если этот метод есть, то он возвращает числовое, а не строковое значение? А то сортировать билеты по цене в алфавитном порядке не очень логично.

Comment: Строковое значение и да есть getTicketPrice

Comment: В строковой записи "48" будет больше "1000".

Comment: А как правильно перевести? Как обычно - integer.ParseIn????t

Comment: Да, как обычно.